# SharePoint Foundation 2010 Development environment limitiations

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm trying to develop a solution that requires listing all pending documents in a library but my dev environment does not have the approval WF on it as it is not Standard just Foundation. This makes it difficult to debug it against an active library where i have moderation enabled. How do other devs get around this? Must I install standard and license it?
Thanks

Comment: You should be developing locally against the same version and patch level the QA/Staging/Prod environments are at. This ensures compatibility across development and deployment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test same Approval workflow, you should install SharePoint server 2010. If you are going to use that workflow in your production environment.

Otherwise you can use Sharepoint designer or Visual studio workflow.

You can try workflow import/export feature, but i don't think it's going to work in this case.

Comment: So a developer cannot really develop business class solutions using foundation, they must pay for the full standard version.

Comment: You can develop business class solution, but for using standard features, you have to pay. Thats why one is free and for other you have to pay.